# Is Marriyum Aurangzeb no longer in the Pakistani cabinet?

Tags: government, pakistan, cabinet

Wikipedia lists her tenure a minister ending on August 10,

[image]

but she's still listed as minister on the government's [website](http://www.moib.gov.pk/Profiles/6055/Ministers).

> Marriyum Aurangzeb is the current Federal Minister for Information and Broadcasting, [...]

Confusingly enough however, there's a "former ministers" under her photo, on the same government page. So, is she still in the cabinet?

Answer (score 1):

Radio Pakistan [says](https://www.radio.gov.pk/18-08-2023/murtaza-solangi-applauds-marriyum-aurangzeb-for-running-info-ministry-in-best-manner) on August 18

> Caretaker Minister for Information Murtaza Solangi visited the residence of former Member of National Assembly Tahira Aurangzeb in Rawalpindi and met former Minister for Information Marriyum Aurangzeb. [...]
>
> The Caretaker Information Minister applauded Marriyum Aurangzeb for running the Information Ministry in the best manner for 16 months.

So, it seems Aurangzeb indeed no longer in the cabinet. *Pakistan Today* [puts](https://www.pakistantoday.com.pk/2023/08/18/murtaza-solangi-assumes-charge-of-ministry-of-information-broadcasting/) the transfer on August 17 though (in an article dated next day):

> Minister for Information and Broadcasting Murtaza Solangi assumed charge on Thursday.
>
> Mortaza Solangi arrived at the Ministry of Information and Broadcasting after taking oath at the President’s House.

I guess it's possible Aurangzeb resigned or was dismissed a week before though (Aug 10), but insofar I could not find confirmation.

Caretaker PM "Anwaar-ul-Haq Kakar was sworn in on Monday" (Aug 14) [according](https://apnews.com/article/pakistan-new-premier-independence-day-93f8f4b1adb2458a0817420b6cdf1ce2) to AP. The reshuffling of the cabinet was almost certainly related to that.

On Aug 9 the Parliament [was](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/aug/12/pakistan-appoints-little-known-senator-as-caretaker-prime-minister-anwaar-ul-haq-kakar) dissolved. [According](https://news.cgtn.com/news/2023-08-08/Pakistan-s-federal-govt-to-be-dissolved-on-Aug-9-prime-minister-1m6EiKpQ2WY/index.html) to a CGTN report of Aug 8, the entire Shahbaz Sharif  government was slated to resign the same day (Aug 9), although few other sources seems to have covered that announcement. I guess that's what's counted as Aurangzeb last day in office (on Wikipedia).

Comment: Wikipedia lists Sharif's last day in office as Aug 13 though. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shehbaz_Sharif&oldid=1171628410